# Подключить соц.сети

Tags: android, vkontakte-api, facebook-api

Ища по форумам самые разные способы интегрирования соц сетей, как правило - я натыкался на неявные интенты в надежде, что на смартфоне установлено приложение-клиент, и через это приложение пользователь сможет сделать какие-то действия дальше.

Но однажды я встречал топик, в котором было написан прямо таки отличный способ, который сам автоматически создавал подобную кнопку(+ все действия с соц сетями):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу найти способ с подключением именно подобным образом.

Comment: Вот есть либа https://github.com/antonkrasov/AndroidSocialNetworks
Но советуюю использовать официальные документации социальных сетей.

Comment: @marazmone смысл в том, что есть некий путь настройки, про котором появляется подобная кнопка. Проблема не в подключении соц сетей стандартным способом - а именно в создании подобных кнопок - они появляются автоматически. Видел это с полгода-год назад.

Comment: об этом речь идет? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android#addbutton

Comment: @marazmone да да, вроде это оно, как это называется?